# How to determine when a company will be done with "head counts"

Tags: communication, job-search, recruitment

I have been in contact with a company I want to apply to since about September. For reference it is a Biotech company in NY.

The two people I am in contact with are from recruiting / on-boarding / university relations. I had a pre-screening interview in November for the position I applied to, and as of now am still waiting for feedback.

I met my contacts through my university career fair, and upon the most recent career fair one of the more senior people there (a contact of mine now through LinkedIn of his volition) knew of my application.

When I asked him my "status" he said the company was trying to get a "head count" of people needed since they are expanding, and I guess he could not give me an exact answer.

What I want to know is how long this "head count" process usually takes, or if I can contact them in a "proper" way to determine my status in relation to their "head count". I do not want to sound annoying by sending constant emails.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere      Would giving a call to one of them be a bad move then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how long this "head count" process usually takes

[being 100% serious] Between 1 day and two years.  And even then the project might be cancelled completely.

Having been through this many times, there is no way to tell and, be aware, they probably don't know the answer either.  So, it's not that they're hiding anything, they just don't know.

What's going on is that 4-5 levels higher up in the company, all sorts of discussions are happening and they will happen at the pace that those discussions will allow.